# find and edit data using a form in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

UPDATED - I have the form as shown below. The form can populate the list in the combobox. It can also locate the notes attached to the appropriate username. However, i need it to update the same cell which i am struggling with. I tried to use  Siddharth Rout's (see comments) .find code but dont really understand it or how to make it apply to my sheets.

[image]

To populate the list i used the following

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    With Worksheets("Notes")
        ComboBox1.List = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Since posting this i managed to locate the notes attached to a user name using vlookup function in vba. Using the code below.

```
    Sub CallNotes()

the_value = ComboBox1.Text

If TextBox2 = "" Then
TextBox2 = "No Notes Applied."
Else
TextBox2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(the_value, Worksheets("Notes").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
End If
End Sub
```

The main problem i now face is updating the notes. As soon as the comments button is clicked i need the code to look for the username and then paste the contents of the textbox in the cell next to the username.

I tried it with vlookup but it ultimately failed. I since deleted the code and cant remember exactly how i attempted to do it and cant get it back. Essentially i attempted to reverse the whole vlookup process.

All comments and advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim The_value
Dim The_note
Dim c As Range
The_value = Me.ComboBox1.Text
The_note = Me.TextBox2.Text
Set c = Worksheets("Notes").Range("A:A") _
    .Find(What:=The_value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
c.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = The_note
```

This code comes courtesy of Hans Vogelaar MVP on MSDN 
[See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/51c7dbab-817d-4d7f-b57e-c3d0ee8ff153/macro-vba-vlookup-to-insert-values-into-a-worksheet?forum=exceldev)

Still thanks to Siddharth Rout for your assistance